# multiple || after where

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to have multiple ||'s after my where clause based on the amount of strings in an array.

```
string[] searchStrings = new string[]{"test", "tester", "test3"};

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("FolderPath", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .Where(s => s.Contains(searchStrings[0]) || s.Contains(searchStrings[1]));
```

What it should do is search a folder for files, and if the file name contains each of the keywords from the array then it is put in files. Currently I can hardcode how many searches by adding more ||'s but I am wondering is there a way to do this automatically based on the size of the searchStrings array.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.Any()` for instance:

```
.Where(dir => searchStrings.Any(s => dir.Contains(s)));
```

It will allow to get needed result by checking if directory name contains at least one *searchString* from `searchStrings` collection.

Comment: +1 you are faster. btw this can be shortened by using method group conversions:  `.Where(dir => searchStrings.Any(dir.Contains))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expression for this purpose

```
Regex searchPattern = new Regex("test|tester|test3"); // "test(3|er)?"

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("FolderPath", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 .Where(s => searchPattern.IsMatch(s));
```

You can compose your pattern using:

```
string.Join("|", searchStrings);
```

I think regular expressions after precompiling may be even faster in some cases and gives you a lot more of flexibility